# Cross platform ZIP File System

Tags: java, filesystems, zip, nio

I found this sample class to use ZIP File System in Java. How can I use this in cross platform, I have to run this program from OSX and the ZIP file need to be created in a Windows machine.

```
public class ZipFSPUser {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {
        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 
        env.put("create", "true");
        // locate file system by using the syntax 
        // defined in java.net.JarURLConnection
        URI uri = URI.create("jar:file://windowsIpAddress/zipfs/zipfstest.zip");

       try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
            Path externalTxtFile = Paths.get("/Users/myself/zipfs/SomeTextFile.txt");
            Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("/SomeTextFile.txt");          
            // copy a file into the zip file
            Files.copy( externalTxtFile,pathInZipfile, 
                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING ); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Now this is working fine from Windows machine, but when I try to execute this from my Mac machine I'm getting the error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
```

I tried URIs, `jar:file://usrName:pwd@windowsIpAddress/zipfs/zipfstest.zip` and `jar:http://windowsIpAddress/zipfs/zipfstest.zip` but no luck.

Comment: Does Java let you do `try (resource) { statements; }`?  That doesn't look like any syntax i've seen before... (OK, apparently it does.  Spiffy.  :))

Comment: You forgot to mention what the problem is

Comment: @fvu : please check the Question now. I have edited it.

Comment: Can you try the URI without the `jar:` prefix?

Comment: @ViktorSeifert Without using `jar:` prefix I'm getting the error, `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authority component present`

Comment: From other posts I found through google I'm guessing that it might have something to do with the leading `/`.  Can you try it without those?

Comment: @cHao : try with resource is from Java SE 7. Check this out...
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @ViktorSeifert : No luck with `/`, Now I have to mount that directory to mac machine to execute this.